Get master object from master-detail relationship by SOQL FieldDefinition object
Let's say we have
SELECT DataType
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinitionId='Opportunity_ROW_Segment_Junction__c'

it works fine but is it possible to retrieve e.g. Opportunity as a single field from
Master-Detail(Opportunity)

field result.
I just wanna collect all the masters for particular sObject(s)
both master-detail and lookup

I'm thinking your best bet here would be to describe the object and iterate its fields. When a lookup, check its type, instead of using a query. Wouldn't that be better, or do you need to explicitly do this with the FieldDefinition object?

thanks, Renato. I believe it might be a solution

and @Renato Olivera , are there some limits when it comes to using Schema.Decscribe methods?

I don't know. Might need to check the documentaion on the describe methods for more information, and play around with it and read the logs.

You can try this SOQL: SELECT QualifiedApiName, RelationshipName, DataType  FROM FieldDefinition  WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 't561258__Subject_Related_Teacher__c'   AND ( DataType LIKE '%Lookup%' OR Datatype LIKE '%Master%' )
This will return only Lookup and Master-Details Fields.

this query returms the only one record instead of list. But dev console query editor says that we've got 17 ones. What did not understand?
